# Collapse C++ functions in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

We use `Visual Studio 2012` and I've got a little problem with that. There are some cases when the function/class definition collapse/expand feature is missing.

For example if I mark a class as a `final` class then I cannot collapse this class and non of it's functions. But after I remove the `final` keyword everything works again.

```
class Class // I can collapse this class.
{
// ...
};

class Class final // I cannot collapse this class.
{
// ...
};
```

And there's another problem with `final` classes. The `Go to Definition` and `Go to Declaration` actions not work.

An other example is when I add an explicit return type annotation to a `lambda` function.

```
auto function = []() // I can collapse this lambda.
{
    // ...
    return new Class;
};

auto function = []() -> Class* // I cannot collapse this lambda.
{
    // ...
    return new Class;
};
```

I tried `Visual Studio 2013` at home and if I remember these things are good in that version.

Does anyone know a solution for this ? A patch, an update, an extension or anything else.

Comment: Use MSVS2013 it collapses aforementioned constructs correctly.

Comment: It's a good advice :) and I accepts it at home, but the problem is at my workplace, where it's not my decision :(.

Comment: Well, I don't think MS would consider that bug for fixing in the 2012 version which is quite obsolete already and the bug is not particularly severe. So you have no choice then but live with it.